# Make a div opaque when hovering over another that is not a child of that Div

Tags: html, css, web

I have quite an intrusive drop down nav menu.  The number of items means it displays over the other main content.  This is not such a big deal as its quite a simple page.

What I'd like to do is make the background divs transparent / opaque or hide when the nav bar is hovered over.  Hovering over the nav makes the drop down appear and if at the same time the background divs fade it might turn out to be fairly elegant.

I can alter the div when it's a child of another but in this case it isn't.   (To clarify, it is of course a child but I only want it to be targeted when the nav is hovered over)

I have a layout similar to this:

```
<wrapper>
    <header></header>
    <content>
        <nav></nav>
            <other container> 
                <divToBeAltered></divToBeAltered>
                <divToBeAltered></divToBeAltered>
            </other>
    </content>
</wrapper>
```

I'd like to avoid jQuery if possible.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: How do you alter the div when it is a child of another?  What method do you use, if not jQuery?

Comment: Really weird that you would pseudo your div names.

Comment: @JakeSmith - You can do it in css.  #content:hover #divToBeAltered {background:bada55;}
Will change the colour of the div when it's parent is hovered over.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall - That's not the actual names of the divs.  Figured it'd be easier to read.

Comment: I know, but real code is typically easier to try to figure out a solution. If someone did try to solve this, they would have to rename your posted structure rather than fixing what you currently have.

Comment: @ChristopherMarshall - IT'S IDENTICAL IN STRUCTURE. IT WAS MEANT TO BE EASIER TO READ.

Comment: @user2608855 - You're asking a question to developers, the code we work with every day is easy enough (remember, we read this stuff every day, it's fluent to us). While your intentions are noble and we appreciate the concern, it is, to be honest, unnecessary and slightly misled.

Comment: No need to yell ;} You can see in the first answer what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the css sibling selectors. http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

In this case, do something like

```
nav:hover + othercontainer divtobealtered{
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help instead of taking the time out of your day to be a question critique.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Yeah no problem but take their comments with a grain of salt as well. Add comments inline or something.

Comment: lolololol even had to get in on the unnecessary editing action. 

I'm still having a struggle to get it working but At least I know the direction of travel now, failing that jquery wins. :)

Comment: I corrected the syntax, and your question is being criticized since other developers may be searching for a similar solution and it's important the question is structured properly. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 2):

Seems like I'm late to the party. I built a similar solution to @cowboybebop one in a jsfiddle to test it.

http://jsfiddle.net/x2dY2/

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>ONE</li>
    <li>TWO</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section>
  <div>Test</div>
</section>
```

css

```
nav:hover+section div {color: red}
```

Comment: You might just be the most beautiful man who has graced us with his presence today.  I thank you. :)

Ps. Check your syntax...just in case :)

Comment: @cowboybebop deserves the props for this not me - he typed faster than I did :-)

Comment: Amended, got a bit trigger happy :)